# Is the sheafification of a presheaf of graded modules graded?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme, and $F$ be a presheaf of graded $O_X$-modules (give $O_X(U)$ the trivial grading for every open set $U$). Does the sheafification of $F$ also have a graded structure such that the natural map $i : F(U) \rightarrow F^+(U)$ preserves grading?

Suppose $F(U) = \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n(U)$. Since colimits commute with other colimits, we have that for $p \in X$,  $F_p = \varinjlim_{U \ni p} \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n(U) = \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \varinjlim_{U \ni p} F_n(U)= \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (F_n)_p$. Therefore , the stalks are graded $O_{X,p}$-modules.

My idea is that given a collection of compatible germs $(s_p)_{p \in U} \in F^+(U)$, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, take the degree $n$ components of each $s_p$, which are compatible germs in $F^+_n(U)$. This gives a morphism $F^+(U) \rightarrow \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F^+_n(U)$. I'm stuck trying to show that only finitely many nonzero terms, so we can replcae $\prod$ with $\oplus$.

Edit: By "graded sheaf of modules", I mean that for every open set $U$, $F(U)$ is a graded $O_X(U)$-module, and restriction maps preserve degree.

Comment: sheafification is a left adjoint so it preserves colimits. In particular $(\bigoplus_n F_n)^+ = \bigoplus_n F_n^+$. Of course the latter $\bigoplus$ is to be understood in the category of sheaves, that is it's a direct sum of sheaves (which is *not* $ (\bigoplus_n F_n^+)(U) = \bigoplus_n F_n^+(U)$, but it's still what is the only reasonable meaning one could give to that direct sum)

Comment: @Max: That should be an answer, not a comment!

Comment: @EricWofsey : I wrote it as a comment because I'm not entirely sure what OP means with grading on a sheaf. In my mind, the only sensible thing is what I wrote, but I may be mistaken

Comment: @Max That's what I'm stuck on. Since $(\oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n^+)(U)$ does not always have to be equal to $\oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (F_n^+(U))$,  I don't know if $\oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n^+$ is a graded sheaf of $O_X$-modules. If $X$ was Noetherian, then every open subset will be compact, so tag 01AI  on the Stacks project will imply they are always equal. However, for schemes in general we don't have this.

By "graded sheaf of modules", I mean that for every open set $U$, $F(U)$ is a graded $O_X(U)$-module, and restriction maps preserve degree.

Comment: OP : it would be interesting to add a definition of "graded sheaf of $O_X$-modules" to your post then. Again, to my mind, a sheaf-direct sum is the only sensible definition, but apparently it's not what you have in mind, so it would help if you could add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works:

Let $k$ be a field and $X = \coprod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \operatorname{Spec}(k)$, the infinite disjoint union of $\operatorname{Spec}(k$). Denote the points in $X$ as $(p_0, p_1, ...)$.

Consider the presheaf $F$ that sends every open set $U$ to $T(O_X(U))$, where $T$ denotes the tensor algebra. This is a presheaf of graded modules. The stalk at $p_i$ is $T(O_X(p_i)) = T(k) = k \oplus k \oplus ...$ Note that none of the degree $n$ terms are zero. Let $e_i \in k \oplus k \oplus ...$ be the element with a 1 in the $i$th entry and 0 everywhere else.

Then, consider the collection of compatible germs that is $e_i$ on $p_i$. This is a collection of compatible germs so corresponds to an element $s \in F^+(X)$. Then, the stalk of $s$ at every $p_i$ is homogeneous of degree $i$. Therefore, if $F^+(X)$ was a graded $O_X(X)$-module, there must be an element whose $n$th homogeneous component is not zero for every $n$. This is a contradiction.

Therefore, the sheafification of a presheaf of graded $O_X$ modules does not have to be graded, at least not in the usual way.

Comment: I have trouble understanding why this is a contradiction. Can you expand on why this must be the case? In particular, this seems to contradict Max's argument from the comments, which makes a lot of sense to me - could it not be the case that this behavior you complain about is really a result of switching from direct sums of presheaves to direct sums of sheaves?

Comment: Suppose $F^+(X) = M_0 \oplus M_1 \oplus ...$ as a graded $O_X(X)$-module. Then, $s = (s_0, s_1, s_2, ...)$, and the stalk of $s$ at $p_i$ must be $e_i$. Since restriction to $p_i$ (which is the same as restricting to stalk) must preserve degree, $s_i|_{p_j}  = \delta_{ij}$. In particular, none of the $s_i$ can be zero. This contradicts that in a direct sum, only finitely many terms can be not zero.